# Esptool not found on Mac OS M1 Monterey 12.4

Tags: python, apple-m1

I installed several tools after moving from "port" to "homebrew" but was not able to install es-tools. Python (3.10) would not be able to install it as a model with pip, it does not build it since "reedsolo" has errors.

Is there a workaround since esptool.py is on my system

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution in GitHub : https://githubhot.com/repo/espressif/esptool/issues/711

**python -m pip install --only-binary :all: --extra-index-url https://dl.espressif.com/pypi/ reedsolo**

and

**pip -m pip install --only-binary :all: --extra-index-url https://dl.espressif.com/pypi/ esptool**